# using c++ to convert a txt into html

Tags: c++, html, istream

I'm currently working on a project where I read a textfile to make it into a body code of html.
The problem is whenever there is an enter/newline I have to enter "
" into it.
And...I'm not really sure how I could tell if there is a new line.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

istream findParagraph(istream& is, string& word) {

    //if there's a new line here I need to make sure I add "<br \>"
    //into is; then send it back to main

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    argv[1] = "The Republic, by Plato.txt";
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    char ch = 0;


    ofstream out("title.html");
    out << "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\">" << endl
        << "<head>" << endl
        << "<meta http - equiv = \"Content-Type\" content = \"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />" << endl
        << "<title>" << argv[1] << "</title>" << endl
        << "</head>" << endl 
        << "<body>" << endl;

    typedef map<string, unsigned> dictionary_type;
    dictionary_type words;

    string word;
    while (findParagraph(infile, word))
        ++words[word];

    out << "</body>" << endl << "</html>";

} //end main
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `istream`, the trick is to compare a `char` from the stream to `13` or `10` (depending if you are `LF (ascii=10, found on UNIX-like systems)` or `CRLF (ascii=13, ascii=10, found on Windows)` for newlines.

For example, given that `ch` is the most recent `char` from your `istream` (`LF`):

```
if(ch == 10)
    // insert <br>
```

For (`CRLF`), given that `ch1` is the newest, and `ch2` is the second newest:

```
if(ch1 == 10 && ch2 == 13)
    // insert <br>
```

`13` and `10` are the values for Carriage Return and Line Feed, respectively.

---

That's really all there is to it. It sounds like you can do the rest :)

Comment: Hey Blue Ice. Thanks for your reply.
I just have one small question. what if the user is using windows and the textfile has ASCII = 13 in the file?

Comment: The actual text `ASCII = 13`? Or the value `13`? If it is the value `13`, then it is a Carriage Return.

Comment: I meant the value 13 of ASCII.
What is a Carriage Return??

Comment: You don't need to know exactly what it means- it's a little arcane. If you want, here is [Wikipedia's article on Carriage Returns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return). Basically, it has to do with moving the print head to the beginning of the paper on typewriters. What you do need to know is that it's paired with an `LF` on Windows. It only matters because of conversions between Unix and Windows- it's just an annoying way to make a new line differently that Windows decided to use.

Comment: you may also like to use getline function and that will be easy to add <br> whenever you get new line

Comment: istream findParagraph(istream& is, string& word) {
 char ch;
 while (is.get(ch)){
  if (ch == 10)
   word += " <br\>";
 }

}

I tried this but it's not really working right...

Comment: Sorry couldn't answer my own question within 8 hours.. :( Thanks for help guys